# Need Help. Subquery or Exists... What It Should Be The Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new here so I hope I can explain my problem very well.

I have two tables:

- **Table1** - master table and it has information like: way bill number, date, bill number, price, is it return bill...

  If it is a return bill it has no price, never. And some of the main bills don't have price as well.
- **Table2** - it shows "return bills ID"s and its "main bill ID"s.

To make it clear, I colorized the tables.

I want to show return bills whose main bills have price and main bills price. I don't want to show NULL priced bills.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT mf.ID , mf.Bill, mf.Price 
FROM Fr.Return r 
JOIN BI.Master_Fr mf ON r.Ret_ID = mf.ID
WHERE mf.Date = TO_DATE('01.09.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Problem is I can't get prices. I tried subqueries like `select (select...)....` and `....where exists(select...)...` but they didn't work.

Can you help me, how can I do it?

[image: Table1]

[image: Table2]

[image: Result]

Comment: Kindly provide the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. Then, please give the expected output also. Explain how you arrive at the desired result. People will help you definitely.

Comment: @marc_s yes, I am using oracle, thank you for your respond.

Comment: @Ranagal I think my account is not authorized for creating tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to the Master table twice: once to get the date of the Return bill and once to get the details of Main bill.

From the details you've provided this query should give you want you want:

```
SELECT mfr.ID , mfm.Bill, mfm.Price 
FROM Fr.Return r 
JOIN BI.Master_Fr mfr ON r.Ret_ID = mfr.ID
JOIN BI.Master_Fr mfm ON r.Main_ID = mfm.ID
WHERE mfm.price is not null
AND   mfr.Date = TO_DATE('01.09.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Note the use of different table aliases to distinguish the two references to `Master_Fr`. We are querying one table twice to extract two different result sets. So we need to be able to tell Oracle which set we're referencing: I have used `mfm` for the set of Main bills and `mfr` for the set of Return bills.

Here is a working demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d4ea9e3c29920b9deeb98c742089f9c).

Comment: I am very sorry to post such a question.
I can't share the full query because the table's names include the company name.
This might be a problem for me.
By the way, could the problem be with the Oracle version? 
Verison is 12c.

Comment: Now I see the difference. JOIN Master_Fr mfr ON r.Ret_ID = mfr.ID
JOIN Master_Fr mfm ON r.Main_ID = mfm.ID. You use mfr and mfm. I tried like this and it works thank you so much. I am not familiar with this. Why do I have to querry like different table aliases? (You mentioned above but I hadn't had understood it, so sorry)